# Using Old Mac as Production Server

Tags: command-line-interface, hosting, cloud, mac-osx-server

I am building a web-app and on my server, I need to execute some xcode-command-line-tools, so basically I come up with this architecture :

```
Frontend(React) --> NodeJS(Ubuntu) --> MacStadium(DedicatedHostedServer) --> NodeJS(Ubuntu) --> Frontend(React)
```

So in my dedicated MacStadium I was doing the small Xcode stuff and return it to my node server.
Since MacStadium is very expensive and I don't profit from the website I was wondering if it is possible to use an old iMac I have together with my home connection and macOSServer APP to host my API and replace the MacStadium.
If Yes do you have any resources that explain it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really sure you specifically need Xcode command line tools and cannot use similar Linux tools or even existing NPM packages?

Comment: think so cause i need to change the icon folders of MacOSX which apparently is impossible to replicate on other machine